# jquery live method to bind keydown event does not work in IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have following code to capture keydown event. This works fine in all browsers GC,FF,IE8 except IE9 and IE10.

```
$(_inputSelector, $('td', 'table')).live("keydown", function (event) {
 // some client side logic
});
```

the selector is returning me dom elements properly but its just the event which is not trigger once the code is executed. please advise. thanks

Comment: Why are you not using `on()`?

Comment: I am using older version of jquery which does not support on()  but live() and at this point, can't update the core library since there would be alot of changes required in the application.